# Toggle "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" From Batch File?

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, high-dpi

I have a user with an application that isn't compatible with high DPI settings in Windows 10 (UI gets blurry), and of course enabling the option "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" resolves the issue, but the application updates frequently and thus the user has to re-enable the option frequently to avoid the blurry UI. Does anyone know if there is a way to automate this via a batch file?

Comment: i asked a similar question here https://superuser.com/questions/1168101/command-for-disable-display-scaling. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't.

Comment: I found a workaround which was to simply make a copy of teh .exe file and change the settings with the Compatibility tab. This way I have different copy of teh .exe for High DPI and Low DPI.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case it's and anti-virus software, and it automatically downloads new files to replace old ones (the file would need to be re-copied and modified frequently). I was just hoping that a Scheduled Task could be created to automate changing the setting, since it causes the UI to become blurry on Windows 10, and users have complained about the setting getting reset after program updates get installed.