# command for disable display scaling

Tags: windows-7, command-line, command-line-arguments, scaling

I know you can disable the display scaling factor by right clicking an .exe file and then going to the  Compatibility tab, but I need a way to launch and app from terminal or .bat file with either display scaling enabled or disabled.

Does anyone know if there is a parameter that I can launch with the execute command to disable the display scaling of the application?

Running Windows7 64 bit.

Comment: Have you tried creating a shortcut, changing the Compatiblity properties of such shortcut and then starting it from the command line like: start shortcut.lnk ??

Comment: Yes. I thought of that right after.